# Increase in potential across a Resistor

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, conventions

Sometimes while solving problems Kirchoff's Voltage Law, there comes a resistor placed in such a position that in one of the loops the potential across that resistor is actually taken positive (which shows an increase). My question is how can this be possible, not that I doubt it but i need an explanation  that explains it on the electron level. For example I understand that electrons normally loose energy due to work against the atoms inside a resistor. I need an explanation of how electrons gain potential (or energy) as they move across a resistor in the opposite direction of normal current flow. A microscopic (electron-scopic) scale explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The one thing you can take for sure is that whichever is the direction of the voltage drop, is the direction of the current.   So if a resistor is placed so the voltage goes up, instead of down, it means the current is going to go the other way.  It's a lot like elevation and the flow of water in a river.  The electrons will be pushed in the direction of downward voltage drop.

Comment: But its quite impossible for water to flow upstream. However in a closed loop you have to take current flow in a specific direction which results in the case described. I don't understand the manner in which this potential increase occurs since resistors primarily reduce voltage.

Comment: But if you guess wrongly about the direction of current flow, or you make a sign error in your calculations, then that will resolve your problem.  As Ken G says, if you are sure that the potential drops in a certain direction for a resistor, then the conventional current is definitely in the same direction.

Comment: So you're saying that the increase in voltage is merely a theoretical supposition created to satisfy the problem?

Comment: Water can only flow uphill if it has a huge momentum already, it's generally not the way rivers work.  Electrons do not have an inertia that could flow against a potential rise like that.   Instead, imagine that electrons accelerate over a short distance and are stopped by a collision in the resistor, then do it again.  When they move too freely, they have a way of cancelling out the field that would otherwise accelerate them.  But in a resistor, the field is allowed to build up expressly because of the electron's limited ability to move, and that is why you get a potential drop.